# intellij unable to recognise python imports installed via pip

Tags: python-2.7, intellij-idea

Here is a screen shot below

[image]

I see the import MySQLdb raises an error. This script runs without an error if I run it from a notebook or terminal session.

How do I resolve this to run on my Intellij IDE without "MySQLdb" module shown as error.

EDIT : My IDE recognises python os level modules like "import os"

Thanks,

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems: cannot import manually installed module. I try to add classpath in Mac environment parameters and intellij SDKs, but it doesn't work. My final solution is to add the classpath of the module to Run/Debug Configurations:

Open Run/Debug Configurations and select your unittest class:

> Run --> Edit Configurations...

Add your module's classpath to Environment variables: 
[image]